# Can I add a new package to my existing project in Android Studio?

Tags: php, android, mysql, eclipse, android-studio

How can I add a new package to my existing project in Android Studio?

I had referred [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/). In this link they said to create an app and helper package in Eclipse, but I am using Andriod Studio, and I know basic programming. Even this link has JASON success and error files, these files have to be created in php or not required.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can add libraries like so:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
  compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
  compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
  compile files('libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar')

}

repositories {
   maven {
      url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**
To add a new package to android studio, click on Project -> expand the 'app' directory, expand 'src' -> expand 'main' -> right click on 'java' -> New -> Package.

Comment: sorry ...i was still in confusion is adding package and library means the same??

Comment: It depends on what you're adding.  If you adding a jar (which is not a library), you can add it like the examples above.  If you're adding a library, you can get one from a repository, or just add it like above.  What are you adding?

Comment: first of all i really thank u fr ur patience..actually i like to java files for creating loin activity ..where i have to place some of java files in app package and some in someother name pakage folder..bt i dont know how to do it

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you add a package to your project in Android Studio.

Answer (score -2):

First open the project in **Eclipse** and select *File->Export*

then on **Android Studio** click on *File->New->Import Project*

Comment: i dont have eclipse right now...more over i tried to implement the project which i was mentioned in the url so now u have understood that this is a new project directly i have created in android studio

Comment: @basanthUppalancha If you are a real beginner to android programming i would'nt suggest you to start with a project that big

Comment: i am trying to start with basic activities only...for login verification for my app ...which is a basic one....

Comment: @basanthUppalancha Yes i suggest you to better start adding activities to you project  as necessary and override its .xml and .java files with the one provided in the example